# Not able send Email using coltware lib in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

We are working on Flex technology to develop a desktop application, in which we will send mail to specified users.

We have used coltware library to send email to users. But the system is not sending email. We have checked code and there system is not showing any error in this.

My code is:

```
sender = new SMTPSender();
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.HOST,"smtp.mandrillapp.com");
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PORT,587);

sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.AUTH,true);
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.USERNAME,"myusername");
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.PASSWORD,"mypassword");

message = new MimeMessage();
from = new INetAddress("sendfromEmailID", "From Label");
message.setFrom(from);
toRecpt = new INetAddress("sentToEmailID", "To Label");
message.addRcpt(RecipientType.TO,toRecpt);

message.setSubject("Email from Test Application");
message.setTextBody("Hello User");
sender.send(message);
sender.close();
```

Can you please tell us? Is anything worng with above code. if not, then why the system is not sending email??

Waiting for solution.

Comment: Check your app's log - the coltware code writes to it; that should help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks, we have checked the log and there is no error found in log except debugging log. Coincidently, system sent an email only one time after that we have tried many times with same code, but no email sent by system.

Comment: It could be useful to check serverside logs aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Does Mandrill requires two-step authentication? (OAuth, OpenAPI)?
Also check if it needs tlsocket to be specified

```
var tlssocket:TLSSocket = new TLSSocket();
sender.setParameter(SMTPSender.SOCKET_OBJECT, tlssocket);
```